# I got an Error " 'Piksel\Modules\DB\PDO' not found " for abstract class namespace

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces, abstract-class

I want to use namespace for may project but I have a problem with it.
I got an error like that

> "Fatal error: Class 'Piksel\Modules\DB\PDO' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\modules\database\DataBasePDO.php
>   on line 23"

Here is my index.php code;

```
use Piksel\Modules\DB;
require_once("includes/require.php");


class Main extends DB\DataBase
{
    static function getdata()
    {

    }
}

$db = Main::getInstance();
```

and DataBasePDO.php code is;

```
    <?php namespace Piksel\Modules\DB; ?>
    <?php

    require_once(sprintf("%s/IDataBase.php", __DIR__));
    require_once(sprintf("%s/DataBaseParam.php", __DIR__));
    require_once(sprintf("%s/QueryMaker.php", __DIR__));

abstract class DataBase extends QueryMaker implements IDataBase
{   
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected $DBH;
    protected $STH;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct() 
    {
        $dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;", $this->getHostName(), $this->getPort(), $this->getDbName());

        try 
        {
            $this->DBH = new \PDO($dsn, $this->getUserName(), $this->getPassword(), array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
        catch (\PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->errorMessage($e);

            die();
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank you for advanced.

Comment: There is nothing about `PDO` in your code (except filename). IF you are creating new instance of `PDO` in namespaced file, use `new \PDO();`

Comment: So are you sure that every usage of `PDO` in this file is prefixed with global namespace?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I never used pdo with namespace..